# ItextSharp adding unwanted borders to HTML generated PDF

Tags: c#, itext, openxml, power-tools-for-xml

I am using Power Tools For Xml to convert a word document to HTML. I am then plugging that HTML into the ITextSharp XMLWorkerHelper to create a PDF. This overall process works fine for what I am trying to accomplish with no issues.

The problem I am having is that ItextSharp is adding black gridlines to the a table that is in the generated HTML. The HTML that Power Tools is generating is below. In the styling all of the border styling is set to none. Does anyone have enough experience with ItextSharp to identify what in this html is causing ItextSharp to put black gridlines around the table when it converts it into a PDF?

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<title></title>
<meta name="Generator" content="PowerTools for Open XML" />
<style>
    span
    {
        white-space: pre-wrap;
    }
    p.Pt-Normal
    {
        margin-bottom: 0;
        font-family: Calibri;
        font-size: 10pt;
        line-height: 108%;
        margin-top: 0;
        margin-left: 0;
        margin-right: 0;
    }
    span.Pt-000000
    {
        font-size: 10pt;
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: normal;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    table.Pt-000005
    {
        border-collapse: collapse;
        border: none;
        margin-left: 0;
        margin-bottom: .001pt;
    }
    tr.Pt-000006
    {
        height: 0.23in;
    }
    td.Pt-000007
    {
        vertical-align: top;
        width: 140.75pt;
        border-top-style: none;
        padding-top: 0;
        border-right-style: none;
        padding-right: 5.4pt;
        border-bottom-style: none;
        padding-bottom: 0;
        border-left-style: none;
        padding-left: 5.4pt;
    }
    span.Pt-DefaultParagraphFont-000008
    {
        font-family: Calibri;
        font-size: 10pt;
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: normal;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    td.Pt-000009
    {
        vertical-align: top;
        width: 95.55pt;
        border-top-style: none;
        padding-top: 0;
        border-right-style: none;
        padding-right: 5.4pt;
        border-bottom-style: none;
        padding-bottom: 0;
        border-left-style: none;
        padding-left: 5.4pt;
    }
    td.Pt-000010
    {
        vertical-align: top;
        width: 63.35pt;
        border-top-style: none;
        padding-top: 0;
        border-right-style: none;
        padding-right: 5.4pt;
        border-bottom-style: none;
        padding-bottom: 0;
        border-left-style: none;
        padding-left: 5.4pt;
    }
    td.Pt-000011
    {
        vertical-align: top;
        width: 168.1pt;
        border-top-style: none;
        padding-top: 0;
        border-right-style: none;
        padding-right: 5.4pt;
        border-bottom-style: none;
        padding-bottom: 0;
        border-left-style: none;
        padding-left: 5.4pt;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div align="left">
        <table dir="ltr" class="Pt-000005">
            <tr class="Pt-000006">
                <td class="Pt-000007">
                    <p dir="ltr" class="Pt-Normal">
                        <span class="Pt-DefaultParagraphFont-000008">N/A</span></p>
                </td>
                <td class="Pt-000009">
                    <p dir="ltr" class="Pt-Normal">
                        <span xml:space="preserve" class="Pt-000000"></span>
                    </p>
                </td>
                <td class="Pt-000010">
                    <p dir="ltr" class="Pt-Normal">
                        <span xml:space="preserve" class="Pt-000000"></span>
                    </p>
                </td>
                <td class="Pt-000011">
                    <p dir="ltr" class="Pt-Normal">
                        <span class="Pt-DefaultParagraphFont-000008">CASE NO: abc</span></p>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Comment: There's 356 lines of code in there, do you think you can pare it down to the least amount that reproduces your issue? Also, can you post what code you are using to translate HTML into PDF syntax?

Comment: @ChrisHaas Okay I've removed some of the code.